# How to change the 'hosts' file to redirect URLs?

Tags: networking

For windows machine we got the hosts file to edit to redirect url's to other domains. Is there a file like that on android?

I'm looking to redirect a very long url to a shorter one using the hosts file, is this possible? This can also be used to redirect a list of known spam domains to nothing so the worst flash/gif adds are removed.

I'm running Android 2.1 on a rooted samsung galaxy S

Comment: It should be possible since there is the "AdFree" app for rooted users.  It doesn't look to be open source, however...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original link is dead. I pulled [this short guide from way back machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120412100048/http://laslow.net/2009/12/27/set-hostname-on-htc-dream-rooted-with-cyanogen/), copied here:

> With the first few official Pre-Alpha builds of CyanogenMod 7 being
>   released, it’s worth noting that a new feature has been included that
>   allows you to change the hostname on your device from the Settings
>   menu. If you have a supported device, you can get the nightly builds
>   from the TeamDouche Mirror System. Once you’ve flashed (I take no
>   responsibility if you break something – make sure to read up on
>   issues/pitfalls/requirements before flashing), open the Settings menu,
>   then choose Applications, then Development, and select Device Hostname
>   at the bottom. This setting persists between reboots and ROM upgrades
>   (unless you wipe).
>
> Warning: I accept no responsibility if you brick your phone while
>   doing this.
>
> I ditched my iPhone due to problems my local provider was having and
>   got an HTC Dream instead. I promptly rooted it using the Cyanogen Mod,
>   but noticed that by default, Android reports the hostname as
>   ‘localhost’. I don’t really like this, so I set about finding an easy
>   way to change it.
>
> First off, even rooted, the / partition is mounted read-only when you
>   boot normally, so you need to boot to Recovery Mode (Home+Power). In
>   the recovery menu, choose to boot to console. From there, browse to
>   /system/etc/init.d.
>
> IMPORTANT: Make a backup of ’05userinit’ before continuing! You can do
>   this by simply running the following command – ‘cp 05userinit
>   /05userinit’ (without quotes). This will create a copy of it in the /
>   directory. If you screw up your editing, you can just rm the messed up
>   version and cp the backup back in.
>
> To add the command to set the host name, we’re simply going to echo in
>   the following two lines:
>
> ```
> echo  >> 05userinit
>
> echo hostname NEWHOSTNAME >> 05userinit
> ```
>
> Note that there are two spaces after the first ‘echo’ command. This
>   creates a blank line at the end of the file. The second echo adds the
>   hostname command. This way, whenever your phone boots, the hostname is
>   set. Also, be sure to use two greater-than signs (>), as that
>   appends – if you only use one, it overwrites the contents of the file.
>
> Make sure the edits are correct by typing ‘tail 05userinit’ – as long
>   as it isn’t blank, and there’s more than just the hostname line,
>   you’re golden. Reboot the phone by typing ‘reboot’ at the prompt and
>   hitting ‘Enter’, and you’re done.
>
> Once you’ve booted back up, open up your terminal emulator of choice
>   and type ‘hostname’ (by itself, no parameters) – it should echo out
>   whatever hostname you specified.
>
> Update (April 6th, 2010): To change your hostname on Cyanogen 5.x, add
>   the following line to the bottom of /system/etc/init.d/01sysctl — and
>   make sure you make a backup of 01sysctl before editing it!
>
> ```
> echo NEWHOSTNAME > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
> ```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is only possible on rooted phones. should we add that to the tags?