# How to edit 'etc/hosts' file?

Tags: hosts

I'm using Nexus 5 on Android 4.4. Kitkat. I would like to edit `/etc/hosts` file and add redirect mappings in order to block few ads.

I need to know how to access/modify/replace `/etc/hosts` file.

---

I have already checked below similar Q/A:

- [How to change the 'hosts' file to redirect URLs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/how-to-change-the-hosts-file-to-redirect-urls) -> Link in the answer is broken
- [Guide to editing /etc/hosts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16847/guide-to-editing-etc-hosts) -> Not found a way to edit hosts file.

Comment: If you're trying to do web development, you might not need to edit the /etc/hosts file, you can use [remote debugging with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging).

Answer (score 45):

This is actually a compilation of answers and my own expirience.

So, get/install a copy of ADB, then type

```
adb devices -l # make sure your gadget is listed
adb shell # run a shell there
su # become the root (don't miss confirmation request!)
mount -o rw,remount /system # allow to write
vi /system/etc/hosts ## edit the file in place - do what you whant, then <ESC>:wq ##
mount -o ro,remount /system # get things back to normal
exit # unroot
nslookup YourBlockedAdSite.Net # check if it works
exit # good bye
```

You're done.

- Things after `#` are comments and may be omited from your input. If you cut'n'paste them, it should be safe enough too.
- It's supposed you have root access on your device (or the `su` wont work).
  Actually, you'll be unable to edit the file if you have no root anyway.
- It's supposed you have a busybox installed (otherwise you may miss things like `vi` and `nslookup`). Well, you may still try to play with `adb pull`/`adb push` then.
- It's quite common the `adb remount` fails to work and this is a workaround.

  - **Note:**
    When you run `su` in the shell, you may be asked ***on your gadget*** to confirm!

Comment: Does this work if the device has not been rooted?

Comment: neither su neither vi commands are not present in my case: S6 edge

Comment: Sure, the phone must be rooted first (any linux must be "rooted" to edit files in `/etc`, actually).

I'd recommend [SuperSU  by Chainfire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) application and its busybox - it will give you both `su` and `vi` .

The question "How To Root My Phone" is out of the scope here.

Comment: Old good echo saves me:  echo "1.2.3.4 domain.tld" >> /system/etc/hosts

Comment: echo is good only if you have to add a line.
or to replace the whole file.
in case of any more advanced edit, you'll have to use vi/sed/awk/you-name-it tool.

Comment: [1] I need to use `mount -o rw,remount /system` in Nexus 5X. 

[2]  `vi` is not necessary, you can `adb pull /etc/hosts`, modify it, then `adb push hosts /sdcard/`, and finally do `cp /sdcard/hosts /etc/`.

Comment: I had to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41332316/1756069 to make it work.

Answer (score 17):

Note : ***In-order to edit hosts file your device should be rooted***

You can edit etc/hosts file using [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en) or any File explorers with root access.

**OR**

Check [this](http://www.theandroidportal.com/edit-modify-hosts-file-block-websites-android-root/) method

Answer (score 0):

**Root needed**

Use [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer) app to explore files via PC/Mac. Just copy out `/system/etc/hosts` edit it on your PC and copy and paste the `hosts` file to the same dictionary on your phone.

Comment: How you want to copy the file to that location on android?

Answer (score -1):

save the contents of hosts blacklist into file called "hosts" [no extension at end]

copy it to internal storage on the phone

then via cmd:

```
adb shell
su
cp /storage/emulated/0/hosts /system/etc/
exit
```

DONE, reboot phone

Comment: The system partition needs to be remounted in rw mode for your solution to work. That said, in Android versions supported by Magisk it is better and easy to use systemless hosts which avoids making changes to system partition.