# Couldn't sign in to Google

Tags: google-play-store, connection-issues, google

I'm experiencing this issue from couple of days :

[image]

I have already :

- Disabled 2 step verification from [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
- Factory Reset
- Clear cache from recovery
- Reflash the ROM

Comment: Haven't you tried to call Customer Care?

Answer (score 1):

go to  :

> `/etc/`

//need root access.of course you know this.

then, 2 ways for fix this availabe :

1.Rename this file `" Hosts "` to `" # "`.

need change `Mount R/W` to `Mount R/O` for edit Permission.

2.`Block` or `Delete Block Url/Ip's` in the `Hosts` File

Other Links :

[How to edit etc/hosts file](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60150/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file)

[Cannot connect to gmail account/market](http://androidforums.com/threads/cannot-connect-to-gmail-account-market.36882/)

[Can't add gmail, "Can't establish server connection." Please Help](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-4-kitkat/341053-can-t-add-gmail-can-t-establish-server-connection-please-help.html)

Answer (score 0):

Date and Time errors are most common cause which rejects the connections from Google Servers.

**Go To:**

- Settings > Date and Time
- Set the Automatic Date & Time (recommended).
- Below, you can also set Date and Time manually.
- Reboot the device for calibration of Date and Time.
- Now, try to login to your Google account.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Roaming]