# /etc/hosts file is ignored (android)

Tags: hosts

I changed my hosts file using ES Explorater after root to

```
127.0.0.1 youtube.com
```

but it still takes to the real website, I tried on chrome browser and the default browser. I found the same problem on many forums but it didn't help me at all. can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

Check if the content of `hosts` ends with a line feed. The trailing line feed **is** required.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you turn off Data Saver and any proxies.
From the Google Chrome Support Page:
"If you're using Data Saver, keep in mind that:
...
• Changes you made to your /etc/hosts file won't work."

Source: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392284

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear the data and cache (*this will wipe your bookmarks, addons, etc*) of Firefox for Android for it to pick up the new hosts file.

Answer (score -1):

On the most Android systems, `/system/etc/hosts` is used as the hosts file.

You can read how to change the hosts file from a desktop computer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/110483/62445).